# Mobile Broadband on Ubuntu 18 (Jetson Nano)

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, modem, 3g

I am having trouble setting up cellular connection to T-Mobile with a Huawei E220 stick. It used to be able to connect but it does not connect any more. PIN is disabled, and stick works fine under Windows. I think it might be related to the fact that Ubuntu Modem Manager misidentified the stick as E176?

Please advise.

```
p:~$ lsusb | grep Huawei
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 12d1:1003 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E220 HSDPA Modem / E230/E270/E870 HSDPA/HSUPA Modem
p:~$ mmcli -L
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [huawei] E176
p:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
p:~$ nmcli d
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE                 CONNECTION         
eth0     ethernet  connected             Wired connection 1 
l4tbr0   bridge    connected             l4tbr0             
ttyUSB1  gsm       connecting (prepare)  T-Mo               
dummy0   dummy     unmanaged             --                 
rndis0   ethernet  unmanaged             --                 
usb0     ethernet  unmanaged             --                 
lo       loopback  unmanaged             --
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a reception issue. I put an USB extension cable between the Nano and the Modem and the connection is robust.